# Unable to Fetch Images/JS From Different WebApp(Tomcat)

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have an application which basically consists of about 14 webapps combined. So I have a JSP which tries to load script and images from another webapp. For example on the index.jsp I have:

```
<c:import url="/files/menu_head_section.jsp" context="/APPHomeWeb" />
```

APPHomeWeb is basically a webapp, which is like a dump of most of my applications images, js, css etc.

Now I the menu_head_section.jsp, which is within APPHomeWeb I have other files like:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/APPHomeWeb/files/sharedSources/javascript/generic/onLoad.js"></script>
.
.
.
.
    <span style="float:left;width:100px;"><img src="/APPHomeWeb/files/hz_rgb_grd_wht.jpg" border="0" height="50" alt=""></span>
```

When I load the webpage, I see that the in Web Developer that the files just didn't load with status of 302.

Funnily enough just below that I have the line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dhtmlx/codebase/dhtmlx.js"></script>
```

This loads just fine, with 200.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. But if I was pages would load fine! :)

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just followed a hunch and changed webapp's name from APPHomeWeb to appHomeWeb and it worked. But I have no idea how this worked. Can someone explain me why case would matter here??